# Timeout handling while using run_in_executor and asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.5

I'm using asyncio to run a piece of blocking code like this:

```
result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, long_running_function)
```

My question is: Can I impose a timeout for the execution of `long_running_function`?

Basically I don't want `long_running_function` to last more than 2 seconds and I can't do proper timeout handling within it because that function comes from a third-party library.

Comment: You could possibly try wrapping `loop.run_in_executor()` in `wait_for()`, which takes a timeout parameter.

Comment: That works indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for):

```
future = loop.run_in_executor(None, long_running_function)
result = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout, loop=loop)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The expression will throw a `asyncio.futures.TimeoutError` when timeout is reached.

Comment: Warning: This is a very dangerous answer. Don't rely on it in production.

It only *appears* to do what you want: https://gist.github.com/coxley/5879f5ceecfbb4624bee23a6cef47510

Comment: @coxley I tried your example and I can't replicate your error. It works as expected by not printing 'hell yeah'. What python version are you running? I'm running python 3.6.8. Maybe what the issue you mention was already fixed?

Comment: @chilicheech: Python 3.7 when I made the gist, 3.8.5 when I reproduced it just now.

It's not a bug to fix, per se. More of a "gotcha". Asyncio cancellation plain doesn't affect work inside an executor. The future waiting for the result is cancelled as intended.

Answer (score 11):

A warning about cancelling long running functions:

Although wrapping the `Future` returned by `loop.run_in_executor` with an `asyncio.wait_for` call will allow the *event loop* to stop waiting for `long_running_function` after some `x` seconds, it won't necessarily stop the underlying `long_running_function`. This is one of the shortcomings of `concurrent.futures` and to the best of my knowledge there is no simple way to just cancel a `concurrent.futures.Future`.

Comment: Hi Jashandeep, what do you mean by "won't necessarily stop"? Do you mean "won't stop" or can you point out any condition based on which it won't stop?

Comment: By the way, aren't we talking about an "asyncio.futures.Future" object (as opposed to "concurrent.futures.Future") ?

Comment: It won't stop immediate; i.e. the function will run to completion. So, if there is a `while True: ...` loop in there, it will never stop. --- The default executor in `asyncio` is a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, which in-turn makes use of `concurrent.futures.Future`. `run_in_executor` calls `Executor.submit` & wraps the returned `concurrent.futures.Future` to a `asyncio.Future` such that when one finishes so does the other.

Comment: would the `ThreadPoolExecutor` respond to a manual cancel? (presumably called once the `TimeOutError` is raised?

Comment: No it cannot. On cancellation executor will not schedule next task to the pool but it doesn't stop already executed job.
Literally there are no way to gracefully stop a thread using Python API. Hackery approaches are exist but they are very unreliable, I don't recommend them.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, the timeout is raised but the blocking function keeps running so the script just hangs. I see these comments are 2 years old, is there a workaround now?

Answer (score 0):

although not using `run_in_executor`, i have some workaround about "wrap a block function async with timeout handling"

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time
import ctypes


def terminate_thread(t: threading.Thread, exc_type=SystemExit):
    if not t.is_alive(): return
    try:
        tid = next(tid for tid, tobj in threading._active.items() if tobj is t)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("tid not found")
    if ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, ctypes.py_object(exc_type)) != 1:
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")


class AsyncResEvent(asyncio.Event):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.res = None
        self.is_exc = False
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def set(self, data=None) -> None:
        self.res = data
        self.is_exc = False
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(super().set)

    def set_exception(self, exc) -> None:
        self.res = exc
        self.is_exc = True
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(super().set)

    async def wait(self, timeout: float | None = None):
        await asyncio.wait_for(super().wait(), timeout)
        if self.is_exc:
            raise self.res
        else:
            return self.res


async def sub_thread_async(func, *args, _timeout: float | None = None, **kwargs):
    res = AsyncResEvent()

    def f():
        try:
            res.set(func(*args, **kwargs))
        except Exception as e:
            res.set_exception(e)
        except SystemExit:
            res.set_exception(TimeoutError)

    (t := threading.Thread(target=f)).start()
    try:
        return await res.wait(_timeout)
    except TimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError
    finally:
        if not res.is_set():
            terminate_thread(t)


_lock = threading.Lock()


def test(n):
    _tid = threading.get_ident()
    for i in range(n):
        with _lock:
            print(f'print from thread {_tid} ({i})')
        time.sleep(1)
    return n


async def main():
    res_normal = await asyncio.gather(*(sub_thread_async(test, 5) for _ in range(2)))
    print(res_normal)  # [5,5]
    res_normal_2 = await asyncio.gather(*(sub_thread_async(test, 2, _timeout=3) for _ in range(2)))
    print(res_normal_2)  # [2,2]
    res_should_not_get = await asyncio.gather(*(sub_thread_async(test, 5, _timeout=3) for _ in range(2)))
    print(res_should_not_get)  # timeout error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```