# Handling timeouts with run-in-executor and asyncio and processPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, process, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio and ProcessPoolExecutor to run a piece of blocking code like this:

```
result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, long_running_function)
```

I don't want long_running_function to last more than 2 seconds and I can't do proper timeout handling within it because that function comes from a third-party library.

What are my options?

1. Add a timeout dectorator to `long_running_function?`  https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/
2. Use Pebble  https://pebble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pools-and-asyncio

Which is the best option?

This q is very close to [Timeout handling while using run_in_executor and asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452590/timeout-handling-while-using-run-in-executor-and-asyncio), for which no workaround was reported.

It's been a few years. *Is* there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no control over the target long-running code, this is tricky. If that is Python, however, it should be possible to modify the called function by decorating it (i.e. having a wrapper call to the other function) - the problem is, wrappers can't add timeout checking code *inside* the other function. And they can't "kill" it after a timeout, even it is called in another thread.

But, since you are running things in other process: unlike threads, subprocess *can* be killed from an external thread in another process. *But* you are running a concurrent.futures compatible executor: simply killing the target process would kill one of the workers, and ordinry stdlib's `ProcessPoolExecutor` would just be crippled if you did that - probably taking the whole executor down.

If Pebble's docs say that one of their specializations is exactly to allow timeouts when running things in an executor - so, that is the way to go.

Without recurring to Pebble, though, here is what I'd do: have a target controlling wrapper function that would be called by the executor: it would create a single working process and handle timeouts by killing their working process if needed. (And it could even handle control events sent over a queue).

Or, to reduce the overhead of one extra process per worker, I'd maybe create a specialized Executor that would handle the timeouts, using the main process asyncio loop itself (that is likely what Pebble already does).

But yes, having a "timeout" for ProcessPoolExecutor tasks could be an enhancement Python could see in a future version - one can "vote" for it in the language's official topic for ideas at https://discuss.python.org/c/ideas/6

(It would be *possible* to write such control code here, but taking in account all edge cases relating to subprocesses would be reinventing well oiled wheels that already exist on the stdlib and Pebble, and likely not be suitable for all cases - although it would certainly work for simple cases)

Comment: Hi @jsbeueno, thanks for the extensive answer. I'm still digesting it, but just to confirm, you're saying this approach of adding a timeout decorator is not a good option, right? https://pastebin.com/kv8ts7Ac
\
My understanding is that the decorator would cause the function to throw after `n` secs, thus the process would be freed up. In principle, it makes sense to me, but I see that it is complicated in a multi processing context. I''ll dig deeper and read your answer again.

Comment: my answer is basically: if this can work through Pebble, do it.  And Pebble's documentation seems to indicate it does. Getting this _working_ is not too hard, but getting this working _correctly_ would be, and Pebble had been there.

Comment: Ok will do. I'm not entirely clear  why adding a timeout decorator onto the long running function isn't good enough. The idea is to have the long running function raise an exception after `n` seconds to explicitly halt the process. 


https://pastebin.com/kv8ts7Ac

I'm not sure what are the edge cases here, say for this example specifically/ 

(I agree Pebble seems like the best approach abstractly, but not sure why concretely)